# Scroll appear near collapsed button in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, responsive-design, navbar

I am writing a responsive website using bootstrap, but when I try to resize the window, the collapse button of the navbar didn't show up. Instead, it makes a scroll next to it.

Screenshot:

[image]

```html
<section class="first" >
        <div class="layer"></div><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top conta">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand list" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 
     
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#"  class="list">First Item</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="list">Second Item</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="list">Third Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: First provide full code of css. what are you apply in "first" class and other. I have check your html not any issue on it. so better you provide css related to above html then easy to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Code Snippet is not replicating your issue but in your CSS you could try:

```
.navbar-header {
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
```